# WooCommerce add to cart redirection: Change the destination page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I'm using [woocommerce](https://woocommerce.com/)'s `[add_to_cart_url id=xxxx]` to redirect to the basket page when clicking on a product, but it's not redirecting to the right page. I have changed the settings but it's still redirecting to the wrong page.

Can this be achieved in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect`** filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'add_to_cart_custom_redirection', 999, 1 );
function add_to_cart_custom_redirection( $url ) {
    // HERE set your redirection link (here to cart page)
    $url = wc_get_cart_url(); // for checkout page use: wc_get_checkout_url();

    return $url;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.*